# Safe Mac-bundles up-to-date?

Tags: macos, applications

I like the idea of mac bundles where a group of awesome apps are offered in a very good price. I did bought some bundles before and I would like to know, which is the safiest way of tracking such as bundles deals?

I bought 2 bundles, and both was article in apple/mac blogs. So is any website keeping track of mac bundles, but bundles that are not scams/fake/virus etc.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't followed them for a while, so I don't know if they reliably catch all the bundles, but I followed http://dealmac.com back in the day.

They track lots of hardware deals and some software.

Comment: nice one but not to many deals for software